# UIImageView - How to change speed of reverse animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have the following code which animates a volume meter:

```
float meterIndexFloat = volume * 6;
int meterIndex = (int)roundf(meterIndexFloat);
NSMutableArray *litImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i=0; i < meterIndex; i++) {
    [litImages addObject:[volumeMeterImages objectAtIndex:i]];
}

volumeMeter.animationImages = litImages;
volumeMeter.animationDuration = 0.4;
volumeMeter.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[volumeMeter startAnimating];
```

It works well, but I would like to slow down the animation when it reverses itself. Right now the duration is 0.4, but I would like to have it slow down to say 0.7 when the images go in the opposite direction. What's the easiest way to modify it to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to use separate Animation block for this.